# MathLink related error on HPC

Tags: parallelization, scripting, mathlink-or-wstp

Most of the times, Mathematica gives the following error for the jobs submitted on **multiple nodes** in queue:

`MathLink could not create temporary directory /tmp/MathLink: file exists The program may not function correctly`

`MathLink could not create temporary directory /tmp/MathLink: file exists The program may not function correctly`

.....multiple times.

But the same program does not give this error if submitted on a **single node**.

Kindly help.

Comment: I've seen this too, but it did not happen every time. In fact I could not reproduce it consistently. However, I did not notice any ill effects. I remember I looked in the /tmp directories of compute nodes and found a lot of old junk files from Mathematica/MathLink. I asked the administrator to remove them, which made these errors go away temporarily. I could not remove them myself, as they were created under different user accounts on the HPC cluster.

Comment: Hi, adding `$TemporaryDirectory = "to some local path on my account" ` may sort it out ? because there I myself may delete the files ?

Comment: @Szabolcs, Can I hide this error/warning ?